# How to simulate a seamless loop of floating particles?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make a scene where we have a few particles moving around a goal. The physics type is [Boids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids) so they don't fall and they have a nice randomness (The motion looks exactly like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amZ1pRvN6D0)), but because of that randomness I don't think you can make a seamless loop out of it. Is it possible to simulate a motion similar to the video but making it "procedural" so you can loop it?

Comment: Instead of moving them randomly you can keyframe them andat the end of the Timeline put the same keyframe as at the beginning?

Comment: I tried to use a displacement instead and animate the rotation, it looks kinda similar